# External monitor colors are bad

Tags: drivers, hdmi, amd-graphics, 18.10, external-monitor

My friend, is running a dual booted desktop, Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04, he has vga amd radeon hd 5450.

He had an old lg monitor, which connects to desktop the vga port everything was great. he bought a campomatic TV which connects to the desktop via the HDMI port. On windows 10, everything is great still but not on Ubuntu, the colors are too dark and hard to look at.

How to fix it? Is it a problem related to the drivers? I don't think so because if that's the case, should he have a problem regardless of the monitor used? Is there an HDMI driver?

Is it a common problem?

**Edit**

My friend has edited the following settings on windows to make it look good, what is the equivalent on ubunt? "color temperature at night"

[image]

Comment: By the way, I have dual montior, ubuntu 16.04, even I can notice a difference in colors between the monitor and the screen laptop, but not as sever as him, he has only 1 monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He used `brightness-controller`, didn't work perfectly but better than nothing, if you have a better answer, I'll upvote it and accept it.